# Is it reasonable to simplify "Checking for existing SSH keys" to "Check existing SSH keys"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I am learning this [post](https://help.github.com/en/articles/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys), whose title is "Checking for existing SSH keys".

> #### Checking for existing SSH keys
>
> Before you generate an SSH key, you can check to see if you have any existing SSH keys.
>
> Note: DSA keys were deprecated in OpenSSH 7.0. If your operating system uses OpenSSH, you'll need to use an alternate type of key when setting up SSH, such as an RSA key. For instance, if your operating system is MacOS Sierra, you can set up SSH using an RSA key.

Is it grammatical, idiomatic and clear if I simplify that to "Check existing SSH keys"?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Disclaimer: I don't know anything about SSH keys.*</sup>

---

> 1. Checking for existing SSH keys
> 2. Check existing SSH keys

They mean two different things.

*Check for something* roughly means *look/search for something*. So 1. roughly means *looking for SSH keys*. In other words, you don't know if any exist, but you are going to look/search and find out.

In 2., without *for*, you assume/know there exists SSH keys (at least one) and you are going to check them. Here, *check* roughly means *examine, inspect, assess, etc.* In other words, 2. roughly means *examine existing SSH keys.*

Answer (score 0):

Your example phrase is a section header (headline). If you say:

> ## Checking for existing SSH keys
>
> or
>
> ## Checking for keys

It means “the following chapter is about checking for keys.”  The reader will expect to learn about the checking, perhaps *whether or not* to do it, or *how and when* to do it.”

If you say:

> ## Check for existing SSH keys
>
> or
>
> ## Check for keys

It may be interpreted as the **imperative**: “You need to check for keys, and the following chapter shows you how you should do it.”

It suggests (implies) that checking is **necessary**, and this is the chapter that describes how to do it.